# How to remove users from `im.list`

Tags: slack, slack-api

[im.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list) returns a list of all open direct message channels for the given user.

[im.close](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.close) closes a direct message channel but doesn't remove it from the `im.list`.

It's still on the list even if im.close returns `{"ok":true,"no_op":true,"already_closed":true}`

Is there any way to remove the channel/user from the `im.list`?

Comment: Don't believe that is possible. But why would you want to do that in the first place? As you can see from the response it will tell you when the IM is no longer open. (e.g. `"no_op": true`)

Comment: If you can't remove them the list will only get longer and longer. In a workspace with a few hundred of users it will become quite overloaded after a certain time.

Comment: I get that is bothers you, but I do not see that it has any consequence. All you need to do is filter the received list properly. Everything else will be handled internally by Slack.

Comment: Then how can I filter the list? It only contains a flag if the ust is deleted which I guess refers to actually deleted users, e.g. when they left the company.

Comment: I double-checked and you are correct. You can only filter out ims from deleted users, but not closed ones. This is indeed a bit odd, but I do not see any way to change that. Also the new conversations methods give the same result.